# jstack: no providers installed on windows in docker

Tags: windows, docker, jstack

I use a windows Docker container based on `microsoft/nanoserver` (actually based on [the jenkins slave image](https://github.com/JonCubed/docker-jenkins-jnlp-slave-windows)).  `jstack` fails to work in this container as follows:

```
C:\>jstack 39624 
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated
39624: no providers installed
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

This happens with Oracle, OpenJDK and Zulu 8.

Answer (score 0):

The docker container was missing `c:\windows\system32\advapi32.dll`.  Once I copied it from the build host, everything worked.

After some investigation with [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), that was the missing piece.  Every JDK I tried has a `jre\bin\attach.dll` that is presumably loaded by the code in **WindowsAttachProvider**:

```java
// native functions in this library
static {
    System.loadLibrary("attach");
}
```

So loading `attach.dll` in Dependencies gave me the likely culprits:

[image]